# Koding Integration not showing up in services

Tags: gitlab

Recently there was an update that said that Koding was added to GitLab and I have been trying to figure out how to enable it. I go into "Services" where the project settings are all located like the tutorial says but Koding is not there to enable.

Has anyone else figured out how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized it was posted that it is not yet availble.